# How to detect shake gesture in swiftUI

Tags: uikit, swiftui

In apple's documentation, I did not find any gesture related to shake for swiftUI. So how to detect it?

I am very new to swift programming and this question really bothers me for a long time.

In UIKit If I want to detect shake gesture is quite simple and straight forward. In swiftUI, there are bunch of gestures like tap drag rotation, however I cannot find shake gesture in official documentation or anyone who asked. Is this possible in swiftUI to achieve the same result? Or they just forget to add it into the swiftUI framework...

If it's not possible in swiftUI, then how am I going to import the motionEnded function in UIKit to the swiftUI view that I want to detect shake motion?

Comment: Its in CoreMotion and not SwiftUI.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983869/detecting-shake-gesture-by-coremotion

Answer (score 13):

You can add a new notification and override `UIWindow.motionEnded` in an extension (as also mentioned in an earlier answer):

```
extension NSNotification.Name {
    public static let deviceDidShakeNotification = NSNotification.Name("MyDeviceDidShakeNotification")
}

extension UIWindow {
    open override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.motionEnded(motion, with: event)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .deviceDidShakeNotification, object: event)
    }
}
```

With this in place, it's easy to subscribe to the notification in your view:

```
struct Example: View {
    @State private var message = "Unshaken"

    var body: some View {
        Text(message)
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .deviceDidShakeNotification)) { _ in
                self.message = "Shaken, not stirred."
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI does not have a built-in way for detecting the user shaking their device, but it is simple to implement one by overriding `motionEnded()` in `UIWindow` and adding a new view modifier.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

// The notification we'll send when a shake gesture happens.
extension UIDevice {
    static let deviceDidShakeNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue: "deviceDidShakeNotification")
}

//  Override the default behavior of shake gestures to send our notification instead.
extension UIWindow {
    open override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if motion == .motionShake {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: UIDevice.deviceDidShakeNotification, object: nil)
        }
    }
}

// A view modifier that detects shaking and calls a function of our choosing.
struct DeviceShakeViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let action: () -> Void
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear()
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.deviceDidShakeNotification)) { _ in
                action()
            }
    }
}

// A View extension to make the modifier easier to use.
extension View {
    func onShake(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(DeviceShakeViewModifier(action: action))
    }
}

// An example view that responds to being shaken
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Shake me!")
            .onShake {
                print("Device shaken!")
            }
    }
}
```

Source: Paul Hudson has written an excellent post on [How to Detect Shake Gestures in SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-shake-gestures).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the ViewController level. For example:

```
final class MyVC: UIHostingController<ContentView> {

    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard motion == .motionShake else { return }

        // Notify view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this work using a view controller inside of a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` view.

Corresponding `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and `UIViewController`:

```
struct ShakableViewRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ShakableViewController {
        ShakableViewController()
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ShakableViewController, context: Context) {}
}


class ShakableViewController: UIViewController {

    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard motion == .motionShake else { return }

        /* Do something */
        print("Shaken")
    }
}
```

How to implement it:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ShakableViewRepresentable()
                .allowsHitTesting(false)

            /* Other views, in VStack or whatever it may be */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Here is a onShake modifier version based on that: https://gist.github.com/ralfebert/17d4517130bec34c4b80705307e309fb
Currently wondering if this or the UIWindow.motionEnded extension approach is the better one...

Answer (score 1):

iOS 13, Swift 5... a solution that works with SwiftUI based in [jk2K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227031/jk2k) answer, with this obviously this is in the ContentView.swift file.

```
let messagePublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

class ContentMode {

...

}

extension UIWindow {
 open override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event:   UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        print("Device shaken")
        messagePublisher.send("Stop Shaking Me")
    }
  }
}
```

You can than use this to pick it up in your UI

```
.onReceive(messagePublisher) { (message) in
  // message = "Stop Shaking Me"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a refinement on the above with a view modifier.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

private let motionShaked = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

extension UIWindow {
     open override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if motion == .motionShake {
            motionShaked.send()
        }
     }
}

private struct ShakeViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let action: (() -> Void)

    init(perform action: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        self.action = action
    }
        
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
            }
            .onReceive(motionShaked) {
                action()
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func onShake(perform action: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(ShakeViewModifier(perform: action))
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the empty `onAppear()` is necessary but it doesn't work without that.